# Synchronous methods in Meteor/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a function that spell checks a sentence:

```
let spellCheck = input => {
    let corrected = [];

    input.split(' ').map((word, index, array) => {
        G.dictionary.spellSuggestions(word, (err, correct, suggestion, origWord) => {
            correct ? corrected[index] = origWord : corrected[index] = suggestion[0];
        });
    });

    // terrible solution
    Meteor._sleepForMs(200);
    return ['SPELL', input, corrected];
};
```

The issue here is that the return statement happens before the corrected array is filled with the correct versions of the words that have a spelling error. My terrible solution has been to but a sleep function call before the return statement, but I can't rely on that.

I have looked into the option of using Meteor.wrapAsync(), but I don't know which method to use it on. I tried (naively) to make the spellCheck method async, but of course that did not work.

Is there a way to make the G.dictionary.spellSuggestions method itself synchronous?

Comment: G.dictionary.spellSuggestions is an async function.

Your only solution is make spellCheck a async function. Don't use sleep

Comment: @thangngoc89 How would that solve my issue? The same would apply then, since the corrected list would still be empty even if the spellCheck function would run asynchronously.

Comment: By `async` I mean callback, or promise, or async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) on `Meteor.wrapAsync` say:

> Wrap a function that takes a callback function as its final parameter. The signature of the callback of the wrapped function should be function(error, result){}

That last part is key. The callback *must* have the exact signature `function (error, result) {}`. So what I would do is, make a wrapper for `G.dictionary.spellSuggestions` and then use `Meteor.wrapAsync` on that wrapper. E.g.:

```
function spellSuggestions(word, callback) {
  G.dictionary.spellSuggestions(word, (err, correct, suggestion, origWord) => {
    callback(err, { correct, suggestion, origWord });
  });
}

// This function is synchronous
const spellSuggestionsSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(spellSuggestions);
```

What I've essentially done here is packed the non-error results into a single object. If you were to call `spellSuggestions` (async) directly, it might look like this:

```
spellSuggestions(word, function (error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('Got results:', result.correct, result.suggestion, result.origWord);
  }
});
```

So now on the server side, you can use your function synchronously:

```
result = spellSuggestionsSync(word);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got an error message saying that err is not defined? I wish the documentation on this method had a few examples on the Meteor docs.